# Efficient Algorithm for finding area of triangle

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, algorithms, triangles

Suppose a segment is divided into $n$ smaller segments, with each segment length determined by a breaking point chosen randomly and independently. Now take the lengths and divide them into triplets. These triplets will be able to form a triangle if they satisfy the triangle inequality.

What is the most efficient algorithm which will find the area of the largest triangle formed from any of the triplets which form triangle's when combined.

The best I've done so far is sorting by all triples of segments which is rather slow and weak I feel. Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Not suitable for this site, IMO.

Comment: What site would you recommend?

Comment: This a nice question for [https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can do a little better by sorting the lengths first and then for each pair finding the two lengths closest to the hypotenuse of the corresponding right triangle (one from above and one from below). That is $n^2\log n$ instead of $n^3$ you are doing now. Also I would start with looking at the largest lengths first, which might allow you to exclude anything that is too short to compete even if you make a right triangle out of it. After all, the longest intervals exceed the average ones by a factor of $\log n$. Finally, if $n$ is large, you have near independence and exponential distribution.